# Accomplish gallery-type display with a Windows Forms data control and DataTable?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `datatable` that looks like the following:

```
Room   Cook   Waiter  BG_Image
----------------------------------
201    Joe    Jim     Green.png
202    Jack   Mary    Red.png
203    Jet    Mark    Yellow.png
204    Bob    Bing    Green.png
205    Jack   Mary    Red.png
206    Jane   Burt    Red.png
207    Tina   Mark    Green.png
208    Bob    Jill    Green.png
```

I need to bind this data to some type of data control, so that the end-result looks like this:

[image]

Yesterday and today I've been trying to find a solution using the `dataGridView`, but no luck yet.

Ironically, I did the same exact thing in an asp.net webform, and it was much easier with a `DataList`. But with a WinForm, it's been a much more difficult task.

So my question: what data control can I use in a Windows Form to bind to the included `datatable` so that the end-result is something similar to the image I posted?

I'm not asking for a solution to the problem, I'm just looking for a push in the right direction.

(If the question is not well-formed, please let me know and I'll try to change it. And if it's too vague, it's because I have nothing concrete to add.)

Comment: I don't think there's a stock control for this, and making one behave this way would be hell on earth.  You should look to a 3rd party control that's ready out-of-the-box.  BTW...those downvotes are likely either because it's going to require a huge answer (too broad) or because recommending 3rd party tools is off-scope.

Comment: @DonBoitnott, thanks for the post. The issue is that I can't use a custom control because I need to execute C# code when clicking on a cell, and I'm almost sure that I won't have that flexibility with custom controls. It's not just display the image.

Comment: Take a look at [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It allows you to have a grid, where each 'cell' contains other controls, like GroupBox and Label.

Comment: I think you would be pleasantly surprised, then.  I use one myself, and it's quite good.  Lots of aesthetic options and events you could need.  Shop around, see what's out there.

Comment: @ DonBoitnott, What keywords can I use to search for these 3rd-party controls? Unless you're talking about exclusively about Telerik, which is $1,000 a pop.

Comment: Just to be clear, is it really that difficult to achieve something like this in a `winform` and be so easy in an `asp.net webform`? Because this can easily be accomplished with `asp.net's` `datalist` and `ItemTemplate`

Comment: What services of the DataBinding model do you need? Just display? Or navigation? Or editing? Just displaying the data in a DataTable is simple but I can't think of a container Control that provides both real DataBinding and the layout you seek. The DGV will only display rows and while FLP and LV can display what you want, they don't seem to have multi-record DataBinding. Maybe I am missing something, though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloning your design is not hard; and using some sort of `DataBinding` to your `DataTable` to display the data can be achieved with a little workaround.

Things will get trickier, read: need more effort, when you want **more** than simply **displaying** the data. I will not go into that here.

Here is a tiny example:

[image]

The code below only lets your **display** the data. There is no provision for any of the advanced functionality you can get from `DataBinding` like **navigation, editing, validation**..

The issue at hand really consists of three separate problems:

- You want to use `DataBinding` to **multiple** records.
- You want a **free** or tabular layout, **not a row-orientated** one.
- The fields of a record should go into a freely laid out display object.

For the latter there are many options going from a owner-drawn `Panel` subclass to a custom-made `UserControl`. Let's go for the latter as it is simple to code and easier to expand.

For the second we can choose between several container controls. I'll go for a `FlowLayoutPanel`.

But how can we use `DataBinding`? Even if we bind members of the UC we still don't get multi-record data-binding.

The workaround uses the one `Winforms` control I can think of that provides multi-record data-binding: A `DatGridView`. But as it will only display a grid of cells with rows and columns, each cell holding one value, we won't let it display anything at all:

```
DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
DataTable DT = null;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dataGridView1.DataSourceChanged += dataGridView1_DataSourceChanged;
}
```

As you can see the `DGV` is created strictly with the default values but not added to the `Form`, so it doesn't show.

We only use its `DataSource` (after loading the `DataTable`, obvioulsy):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DT;
}
```

When the `DataSource` changes we clear the `FlowLayoutPanel` we use to host the display controls and add one for each `DataRow`:

```
private void dataGridView1_DataSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        UCBind ucb = new UCBind(row, imageList1);
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(ucb);
    }
}
```

The `FlowLayoutPanel` makes life very easy; just make sure its size can hold the right number of display controls! But you could also add them to a `TableLayoutPanel` or even a simple `Panel`. For these you **need** to but also **can** determine **all** the layout **details yourself.**

Now for the display control.

I have created a `UserControl UCBind` and pass in a `DataRow` and an `ImageList` in the constructor. The code looks like this:

```
public partial class UCBind : UserControl
{
    ImageList imgList { get; set; }

    public UCBind()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DoubleBuffered = true;  // prevent flicker
    }

    public UCBind(DataRow row, ImageList imglist)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DoubleBuffered = true;  // prevent flicker
        if (row != null)
        {
            imgList = imglist;
            DisplayData(row);
        }
    }

    public void DisplayData(DataRow row)
    {
        lbl_field1.Text = row.Field<int>(0) + "";
        lbl_field2.Text = row.Field<string>(1);
        lbl_field3.Text = row.Field<string>(2);
        if (imgList != null) BackgroundImage = imgList.Images[row.Field<string>(3)];

    }
}
```

Obviously there is a little more going on in the designer code to style the UC and its fields:

- Add three `Labels`
- `Dock` each to the `Top`.
- Set `AutoSize = false`.
- Enlarge the `Height`
- set their `ForeColor` to `White`.
- Change the `Fonts` as needed.
- Set `TextAlignment` to `Left, Right & Right`.
- Set all `BackColors` to `Transparent`.
- Set `BackgroundImageLayout` to `Stretch`.

You will also want to set the `Size` to what you want.

I have not included the designer genrated code as it tends to be rather long. Simply create the new `UserControl` class yourself, add the `Labels`, styling and the few lines of constructor code above..!

And to make it rich you could try to add resizing code to make the `FLP` always fill with the right number of controls.

Obviously the rounded corners and 3d borders will look best if you don't distort the image. I use an `ImageList` with suitable values for `ColorDepth` and `ImageSize` and load the three `Images`. Then I pass a reference to it to each `UC` I create.. The ImageList is added to the form and you can load the images into it right in the VS designer..:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was able to test it, and it somewhat works.

Comment: The labels display the correct values, but it's not  finding the images (a PNG). I copied the `PNG` in all these folders, but it still can't find it:  path where the _csproj_ is, in _bin_, _debug_, even _release_ folders. And `row.Field<string>(10)` has the correct value (just the name of the image, no path).

Comment: Note that __I have added the Images to an ImageList in the Designer__. The IL is part of to the Form and is __passed on__ to each UC in the constructor. I have added add a few lines and a screenshot about this.,.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was able to display the images by adding them to the ImageList. There's an issue with some flickering, but I'll post another question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say go for a 3rd party control library like devexpress (https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3466) or telerik.

It is really easy to build exactly the same output as your image using WPF. WPF controls are easy to host in a WinForms environment using an ElementHost (see https://dzone.com/articles/hosting-wpf-controls-winforms for an example or just google it)

Hints for WPF: use a WrapPanel as container. See http://www.dotnetperls.com/wrappanel for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some VB code to add an array of textboxes to a FlowLayoutPanel:

```
Sub AddMany(cols As Integer, rows As Integer)
    Dim txt As TextBox
    FlowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight
    FlowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = True
    For y As Integer = 0 To rows - 1
        For x As Integer = 0 To cols - 1
            If Not (x = 0 And y = 0) Then
                txt = New TextBox
                txt.Text = "txt_" & y & "_" & x
                txt.Name = "txt_" & y & "_" & x
                FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(txt)
                AddHandler txt.KeyDown, AddressOf MoveKeyDown
                AddHandler txt.DoubleClick, AddressOf ShowMeta
            End If
        Next
        FlowLayoutPanel1.SetFlowBreak(txt, True)
    Next
End Sub
```

Instead of simple TextBoxes you could add Buttons with images or PictureBoxes. You'd have to paint the text onto the images - or use a custom control.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be doing any DataBinding at all.

Comment: In the portion of the code where .Text and .Name are set you could add the databinding. Note that there isn't an off the shelf solution to display data as shown in your OP. I was just try to show a way to add a "grid" of controls to a container.