# Change format of contents in Windows DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, visual-studio-2015

The qustion I had previously posted was a *How can I do this?* question and didn't completely solve the problem. This question is more specific of the `DataGridView` control. This question is either *Yes, it can be done* **or** *No, the only way is with `flowLayoutPanel` or `tableLayoutPanel` control*.

Our Windows Form has the regular `DataGridView`. Something like this:
[image]

Is it possible to change the format of this datagridview, similar to the `asp.net` data controls with `ItemTemplate`?
For example, make the contents of each cell of the `DataGridView` to look like this:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: No, it still is not possible. - Possible duplicate of [Accomplish gallery-type display with a Windows Forms data control and DataTable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36991351/accomplish-gallery-type-display-with-a-windows-forms-data-control-and-datatable)

Comment: I'm re-asking because the `flowLayoutPanel` you're suggesting will continue having flickering, regardless of what I do to the control.

Comment: And instead of the general "How can I do this?", I'm asking a more specific question regarding the `DataGridView` control.

Comment: Well it can't really be done; DGV display all data in rows and columns, not in display objects; or rather you can if you hide the databound DGV and add a 2nd one. Here each cell would have to know the row from which it can pull its data. Clearly not the normal and recommended way. All other are quite happy with FLPs! - Is the flicker coming while loading or while scrolling?

Comment: It's coming from the loading and the scrolling. It's pretty bad with the loading and even worse with the scrolling.

Comment: How many items are we talking about? And how large are the images?

Comment: It seems to be a common issue with the `flowLayoutPanel` and `tableLayoutPanel` controls.

Comment: 200x200px, and not many items (maybe 30), but enough to display the scrollbars.

Comment: And I can use your suggestion, which is greatly appreciated, but with the flickering I don't think it will be possible. That's why I was asking if the datagridview is similar to asp.net's gridview in the sense that I don't have to use another control to format the contents.

Comment: Well, the thinking is correct but it may still need to do CellPainting for every cell whenever necessary. So you are right, it will not use any other controls but its responsiveness depends on what will happen in the CellPainting event. Which is definitely needed, as a Cell by default can only display one value.

Comment: BTW: I just tested the old code and found adding DoubleBuffering to the UC does help __a lot__ with the flicker when scrolling!