# Any way to optimize populating tableLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, tablelayoutpanel, flowlayoutpanel

I have a `tableLayoutPanel` that I use with a Windows Form. The control is populated from a `datatable` which holds sql server data. I've already confirmed that the `select` statement is not the issue.

The datatable is frequently updated, so the `tableLayoutPanel` is also frequently updated. It's essentially working well, but it gets to a point that it becomes a little slower and that flickering is more noticeable.

Everytime I need to refresh the control, this code is executed:

```
public void FillTlp()
{
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
    tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Clear();

    foreach (DataRow r in DT.Rows)
    {
        UcColor button = new UcColor(r);
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button);//, colNumNew, rowNum);
    }
    this.Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel1);
}
```

Since the will always have 8 rows, I execute the following code in the Form constructor only once, but I don't see much benefit:

```
public FormDoctorMonitor()
{
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear();
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 8; 
    FillTlp();
}
```

How else can I optimize populating the `tableLayoutPanel`?

Thanks.

Comment: Obvious question:  why is "refresh" actually "construct from scratch"?  Change only what needs changed.

Comment: Without having [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to say what the problem is. Just some tips: **1-** Before adding new controls to the panel, first `Dispose` previous controls which you added. Currently you only remove them. You should perform both removing and disposing. **2-** Calling `panel.SuspendLayout();` before removing controls and calling `panel.ResumeLayout(true);` after adding new controls may help.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, where should I add `tableLayoutPanel1.Dispose();`? If I add it at the beginning, I will get runtime error `Cannot access disposed object`. I've modified the sample code with your suggestions; please let me know if they're in the right place.

Comment: @rbhatup please don't edit the question. Currently the edited code will not work. It's better to rollback your edit.

Comment: @DonBoitnott, what do you mean by _Change only what needs changed._?

Comment: Surely you should not dispose the panel, But dispose its child controls. `foreach (Control item in panel.Controls)
    {
        panel.Controls.Remove(item);
        item.Dispose();
    }`

Comment: Implementing your own grid control with TLP is never not a mistake.  Use ListView or DataGridView or go shopping.

Comment: @HansPassant, are you saying that [something like this, with a label in each cell](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mfv0R.png), is easier with a DataGridView ? One of the reasons for using the panel is because this couldn't easily be done with a `DataGridView`.

Comment: It could be easily done using datagridview. Why couldn't be done?

Comment: I posted something similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36991351/accomplish-gallery-type-display-with-a-windows-forms-data-control-and-datatable), and I was told by SO users that it would not be something easy to achieve. The only difference between this and the previous question was that the other one was clickable.

Comment: It depends on rows and columns count.. Also it depends to the complexity of what you want to show in cell. Your linked image can be easily done. Also the linked post is OK.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, you also posted an answer from a user with a [similar requirement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33968993/how-to-create-a-magic-square-using-windows-forms), and you suggested the panel.

Comment: There's nothing I'd like more than to use a DataGridView, but I haven't found a single link showing me how to achieve something like that with this control.

Comment: @rbhatup As I said in previous comment, It depends on rows and columns count. a Magic square is a good example of `TableLayoutPanel`. But if you want to use a `DataTable` with lots of rows will you use TableLayoutPanel?

Comment: Surely the problem of showing some colored label, can be easily solved using both `TableLayoutPanel` and `DataGridView`.

Answer (score -1):

When i have some display freezing, i use those extension methode of control :

```
public static class ExtensionOfControl
{
    private const int WM_SETREDRAW = 11;
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 wMsg, bool wParam, Int32 lParmam);

    public static void SuspendDrawing(this Control parent)
    {
        SendMessage(parent.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0);
    }
    public static void ResumeDrawing(this Control parent)
    {
        SendMessage(parent.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, true, 0);
        parent.Refresh();
    }

    public static void RunWithDrawingSuspended(this Control ctrl, Action code)
    {
        ctrl.SuspendDrawing();
        try
        {
            code();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            ctrl.ResumeDrawing();
        }
    }
}
```

After try this :

```
            this.RunWithDrawingSuspended(() =>
        {
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
            tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Clear();

            foreach (DataRow r in DT.Rows)
            {

                UcColor button = new UcColor(r);
                tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button);//, colNumNew, rowNum);
            }
            this.Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel1);
        });
```

Maybe you can replace "this" by your tablelayoutpanel if already exist on "this"

Comment: If you are going to [take code from somebody else](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487661/how-do-i-suspend-painting-for-a-control-and-its-children), you are required to give them credit for it.

Comment: sorry cody gray... at the time I wanted, I did not think to note the references of the found code. but the extension method is my idea ;) although other there will probably also thought